# Matterport how to add ThreeJs Video Mesh

Tags: 3d, scene, matterport

i'm trying to add a ThreeJS video mesh to a matterport space

here is my code:

```
    const video = document.createElement("video");
    video.src=".......";
    video.onloadeddata = function(){
        video.play();
    }

    const videoTextire = new THREE.VideoTexture(video);
    videoTextire.needsUpdate = true;
    const videoMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: videoTextire,
        side: THREE.FrontSide,
        tonrMapped: false,
    });
    videoMaterial.needsUpdate = true;

    const screen = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10,10);
    const videoScreen = new THREE.Mesh(screen, videoMaterial);
```

now, i have an already initialized matterport space, how can i inject this "videoScreen" into the space?

i know that matterport use ThreeJs under the hood, but how can i add my object?

i tried to create ad object, such as:

```
    const [sceneObject]= await sdk.Scene.createObjects(1);
    var node = sceneObject.addNode();
```

but i don't know how to continue